# Understanding Keras Function - Multi threading?

Tags: keras

I'm playing with `Keras` Function with `tensorflow` backend. I'm trying to understand a behavior I notice:

## Details:

Version A outputs:

```
[[ 1.]]
[[ 2.]]
[[ 3.]]
[[ 4.]]
```

But,
Version B outputs different result looks like threading(the value can be different):

```
Using TensorFlow backend.
[array([[ 0.]], dtype=float32)]
[array([[ 2.]], dtype=float32)]
[array([[ 3.]], dtype=float32)]
[array([[ 4.]], dtype=float32)]
```

What does `K.eval` do that make this kind of different?
Thanks

### Code

#### Basic inc function

```
def inc():
    updates = []
    counter = K.zeros((1,1))
    ones = K.ones(K.get_variable_shape(counter))
    updates.append(K.update_add(counter,ones))
    return updates,counter

updates, output = inc()

f_inc = K.function([],[output],updates=updates)
```

#### Code A

```
for i in range(1,5):
     f_inc([])
     print(K.eval(output))
```

#### Code B

```
for i in range(1,5):
     print(f_inc([]))
```